# I want to fade in a navbar as soon as it comes into view and simultaneously fade out another navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fade

I would like to make the nav with the id "topnav" fade in as soon as it would come into view (if it were visible the whole time). While this happens, I would like to have the nav with the id "hero-nav" fade out simultaneously.

I do not know a lick of JavaScript and honestly I am just looking for someone to come up with a quick solution.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Fonts -->

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Icons -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

    <!-- Stylesheets -->

    <link href="./resources/css/index-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Script -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

    <title>Hood Electric</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="hero">
        <header>
                <div id="hero-logo">
                    <h1>LOGO</p>
                </div>
                <h4><em>"Quality work, done right."</em></h4>
        </header>
        <nav id="hero-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Industrial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </section>
        <article class="testimonies-container">
            <div class="testimonies-div">
            <h2 class="testimonies-text"><em>"The pink shutter shades had me a little concerned at first, but Chris is a very talented electrician."</em></h2>
            <h4 class="testimonies-text">-John Doe</h4>
            </div>
        </article>
        <nav id="topnav">
            <div id="nav-logo">
            <a href="#hero">
                    <h3>LOGO</h3>
            </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#Residential">Residential</a>
            <a href="#Commercial">Commercial</a><a href="#Industrial">Industrial</a><a href="#About">About</a><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="big-pink-div"></div>
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*

COLORS:

Orange #e76000
Gray #585858
Active link gray #585858


*/

/*Global Styles*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}


/*Main jumbotron*/

#hero {
    background-image: url("../images/hood-electric-background.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 95%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;



    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#hero-logo {
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 70%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

header {
    margin-top: auto;
}

header h4 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: #e76000;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#hero-nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

#hero-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

}

li {
    margin: 5px 10px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    /* background-color:rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.212); */
    /* border-radius: 0.625em;
    padding: 4%; */
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

a:hover{
    color:#e76000;
}

a:active {
    color: #adadad;
}

/* Testimonies */

.testimonies-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    width: 100vw;

    background-color: #858585;
    color: #373737;
}

.testimonies-div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #373737;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.testimonies-text {
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

/* #testimonies ul {
    color:#000000;
    width: fit-content;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

#testimonies ul li {

    width: 175px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1vh 2vw;
} */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #topnav {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {

    #topnav {
        background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
        width: 100%;
        height: 8vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        
    }
    
    #nav-logo {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.476);
        margin-right: auto;
        width: fit-content;
        align-self: center;
    }
    
    #topnav a {
        margin: auto 1.5vw;
        
    }

    #big-pink-div {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 8000px;
        background-color: pink;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to do something that requires JavaScript knowledge with zero JavaScript knowledge (not that far along yet), don't have time to learn in time to finish this project.

Comment: SO isn’t an ab initio code writing service. I’m afraid you will have to learn some JS, or learn not to take on projects where you do not have the necessary skills. The bit of JS that would be useful here is IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 0):

we could have to calculate the scroll position and set the fade in/out to the `topnav` and `hero-nav`.

```
<script>
   
    window.onscroll = function() {
        var topNav  = document.getElementById("topnav");
        var heroNav = document.getElementById("hero-nav");

        var topNavOffset = topNav.offsetTop;

        var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if (scrollPos >= topNavOffset) {
            topNav.style.opacity = 1; // fade in 
            topNav.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease";
            
            heroNav.style.opacity = 0; // fadeout
            heroNav.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease";
        } else {
            topNav.style.opacity = 0; // fade in
            topNav.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease";
            
            heroNav.style.opacity = 1; // fadeout
            heroNav.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease";
        }
    }
</script>
```

References:

- [HTMLElement offsetTop property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)
- [Element: scrollTop property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)
- [onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event#using_onscroll_event_handler_property)